# Pycharm : how to import sawtooth_sdk into pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, sdk, pycharm

I am trying to import sawtooth_sdk into pycharm. When I run python3 from cmd and then type

```
>>> import sawtooth_sdk
>>> help(sawtooth_sdk)
```

it succeeds. But I cannot autoimport it into pycharm. How can I import it to pycharm (or even to another IDE)?

Comment: Your question will be specific to package management for the IDE you choose. For PyCharm try https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: Make sure this package is installed on the project interpreter selected in PyCharm settings.

Comment: @FrankC. Thank you!! It worked this way :-)